# Moving System Database Log Files to a different drive make a difference in performance - SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

According to this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb402876.aspx
having the log file and data file on separate drives will improve performance as I/O activity occurs at the same time for both the data and log files.  Based on this information I have moved the non system databases.

Accordingly to this article http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1263294-1550-1.aspx the only system log file that should be moved to a separate drive is the tempDB, the rest won't make a difference in performance as master and model as they are hardly updated.

I want to know from the Stackoverflow community, will it be beneficial to move the System Database log files on another storage drive to improve performance on SQL Server 2012 (master, model, msdb)?

Comment: the sqlservercentral guys are the place to go for sql server questions. I wouldn't second guess them here.

Comment: Looks like I will not be moving the master,model and msdb log files.
The tempdb log file will be moved.  I would separate the tempdb data file too but we have hardware space restrictions.